# Manage content for multiple websites and mobile apps

Tags: asp.net, api, cms

I need to manage content (pages, key/value list, assets and more) in one webbased system for multiple websites and mobile apps.

My idea is to create a web api, secured with tokens for apps and sites and some kind of OAuth authentication, also with JSON web tokens. I want to create it with ASP.net Web Api, Entity Framework and Identify.

My idea is to split up the cms into a single page application, probably in AngularJS, and the Web API. So first create the domain model, how do we need to structure all the content/data and store this. After that create the api. And when that is finished, I need to create a SPA-cms webapplication for the end users.

Every website or app can use the api to read and write data over https and with a secret token, and every other party is free to choose whatever technique or programming language they want to use.

What do you all think about this idea? Can it be a architechture/technique to use for a long time? And do you think this architecture can be used for high traffic websites?

Thanks!

**Edit:** I just want to talk about ideas... if this is the best for this time, to use an API, or just create a MVC-CRUD application with forms and stuff

Comment: There are a lot of details to work out but I don't see a anything wrong with the design so far.

Comment: I can'r think of a good reason to write Yet Another CMS when there are so many out there already. If you are doing this as an exercise you should say so. Otherwise: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#Microsoft_ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

For the edit/admin interface, a SPA is fine.

For viewing the content, though I wouldn't recommend a SPA. Generally, you want to generate static pages from the content a user enters. This is faster/cheaper at runtime (serving static HTML is far easier than reading content from a DB and then rendering a page), and better for SEO. It's the approach used by most CMSs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this better for long run. Isolating core app and providing access through api is good practice currently that way no matter what type of client it is , it can make use of the same environment that web app is using, also there is no need to rewrite api for any specific client

Make sure u have proper access control for resource accessing in API